# Margin around floated element?

Tags: html, css

I am working with a page layout that has a sidebar/callout box that's floated to one side of a large chunk of text content, and the text content may have some notice banners with a different background color sprinkled throughout.

Here is the issue (full JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/midnightlightning/UrsLW/)):

### Undesired:

[image: Undesired behavior]

As the text in the mockup says, note the pink "notice" banner is overlapped by the yellow sidebar (`margin` only kicks the text back, not the edge of block elements that overlap it). I would like it to look more like:

[image: Desired behavior]
With the pink background stopping at the margin of the sidebar. I was able to accomplish this in the mockup by setting a width of the notice banner (because I knew it would intersect the sidebar), but if that notice appears further down the page, it wouldn't expand to the full width, then.

Is there some sort of structure/style that would let me accomplish this sort of appearance, and be flexible as to where the notice banner appears within the content?

Comment: If your background is a single color, you might be able to work around your problem by setting a white border around your yellow box instead of defining a margin.

Comment: Is it important for the red notice to span 100% in width on the line, then stop at the yellow banner?  Or can it just be the width of the text inside of the notice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply add `overflow: auto` to your notice to [stop its background from leaking behind the sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/UrsLW/22), while preserving the margin on the sidebar.

The reason this works is because `overflow` that isn't `visible` interferes with floats as it creates a new block formatting context. Usually, this results in the box simply not intersecting the float (and its margins, if any). Keep in mind that, due to this, if any part of a notice box would otherwise intersect the float, this would cause the entire notice box and its contents to be restricted to the narrower width. You can see this by adding/moving text in the surrounding paragraphs and the notice box itself (I can't easily demonstrate this with a fiddle link).

The spec has this to say, in [section 9.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself [*may* become narrower](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float) due to the floats).

Which points to [section 9.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float):

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by [section 10.3.3.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.

While the second quote sounds daunting towards the end, the behavior you see here is quite consistent, and not an edge case where you would start to see deviations in implementation.

Comment: Didn't knew that, can you explain whats going behind the scenes?

Comment: @Mr. Alien: `overflow` that isn't `visible` interferes with floats because it creates a new block formatting context. I can't pinpoint which section of the spec at the moment (yes, you did say it was my Bible...), but if you're willing to give it a go, see if [section 9](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html) covers it for you.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: OK I found it; I'll quote it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can be clever, and use a white border to hide the contents behind it.

Like this:

```
.sidebar { 
   border-left: 1em solid #FFF;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UrsLW/7/

And the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This seems a little more hacky than clever to me, but I guess it "works"

Comment: It's a bit farfetched calling it a hack.  It's not something you would use everyday, but as per the requirements it works perfectly fine.  Nothing in my answer is outside of the standard CSS usage.

Comment: Ok, I didn't mean "hack", it does work totally well. Just some purists may not approve. What if you didn't have a solid background color or something?

Comment: You could use a transparent border instead. Also you didn't mention that the border *replaces* the left margin that was originally there.

Comment: But what if the background won't be just onle colour but gradient or some other ? :/ If it will be only white I would go for this, but it's not a clean solution well :D

Comment: @BoltClock actually I wanted to write about the transparent border, but that kinda brings us back to the problem :D

Comment: @Ms. Nobody: Ah yes. Backgrounds are painted behind their borders, so that's another issue. That can be solved by using `background-clip: padding-box`, but then that just steps into CSS3 territory.

Answer (score 2):

enclose your SideBar with another wraper

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test
{
    /*moved from your old siderbar*/
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    padding-left:1em;
    /*essential*/
    background-color:white;
}
.sidebar
{
    padding:1em;
    background-color:#FFC;
}
```

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/UrsLW/11/

Comment: Feels like the solution with border to me but with another wrapper instead :D If there isn't just single colour background it won't work out good I think.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to my mind was using CSS3's **box-shadow**, maybe?

```
.sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    padding:1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    background-color:#FFC;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1em #fff;
}
```

Or even a simple border would work, for that matter.

```
.sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    padding:1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    background-color:#FFC;
    border: 1em #fff solid;
}
```

This would work only with single-colored backgrounds, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/UrsLW/5/